# Sending attachment in HTML email with Python

Tags: python, html, email, email-attachments

I saw there are a few somewhat similar questions on stack overflow already, but I couldn't find a solution to my specific problem in them.

I am trying to use Python to send an HTML email with a .pdf attachment.  It seems to work fine when I check my email on gmail.com, but when I check the message through apple's Mail program, I do not see the attachment.  Any idea what is causing this?

My code is below.  A lot of it is copied from various places on stack overflow, so I do not completely understand what each part is doing, but it seems to (mostly) work:

```
import smtplib  
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText                    
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from os.path import basename
import email
import email.mime.application

#plain text version
text = "This is the plain text version."

#html body
html = """<html><p>This is some HTML</p></html>"""

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Deliverability Report"
msg['From'] = "me@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "you@gmail.com"

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# create PDF attachment
filename='graph.pdf'
fp=open(filename,'rb')
att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="pdf")
fp.close()
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)

# Attach parts into message container.
msg.attach(att)
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP()
s.connect('smtp.webfaction.com')
s.login('NAME','PASSWORD')
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I am running this code on a WebFaction server.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

To have text, html and attachments at the same time it is necessary to use both mixed and alternative parts.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

text = "This is the plain text version."
html = "<html><p>This is some HTML</p></html>"
text_part = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
html_part = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg_alternative.attach(text_part)
msg_alternative.attach(html_part)

filename='graph.pdf'
fp=open(filename,'rb')
attachment = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="pdf")
fp.close()
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)

msg_mixed = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg_mixed.attach(msg_alternative)
msg_mixed.attach(attachment)
msg_mixed['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg_mixed['To'] = 'you@gmail.com'
msg_mixed['Subject'] = 'Deliverability Report'

smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('SERVER', port=25)
smtp_obj.ehlo()
smtp_obj.login('NAME', 'PASSWORD')
smtp_obj.sendmail(msg_mixed['From'], msg_mixed['To'], msg_mixed.as_string())
smtp_obj.quit()
```

Message structure should be like this:

Mixed:

- Alternative:

  - Text
  - HTML
- Attachment

Comment: This solution actually solved my issue. And thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @BlowMan I'm glad it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
```

instead of 'alternative'